# Gas with hyperledger Fabric?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, ethereum

With Ethereum, [gas](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/Glossary) is an anti-denial of service measure. What is the equivalent in Hyperledger Fabric to avoid abuse of chaincode invocation transactions ([INVOKE](http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/protocol-spec/#3.3-Chaincode))? Is the NVP expected to check this abuse?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From what I understood, there is no need for such a gas system in Hyperledger Fabric.

The blockchain is supposed to work in a "private" mode, meaning that you know the other peers in the network. It would be easy to detect a malicious peer and revoke its access. Also, there is no "mining" process, only consensus rules triggered for each incoming transaction. This results in a lighter block generation process compared to Bitcoin or Ethereum for example.

However, you can still implement your own custom gas system with a chaincode that add some kind of "transaction fee" before validating any Invoke transaction, but I don't think it would be possible to "mine" gas in the current state of the project.

Comment: thanks. I get all of that. Given that, Hyperledger is focussed on a 'permissioned' network, trust is sort of implicit. But, taking it to the extent, where we don't check for DoS out of box is a bit of a stretch. If push came to a shove, I would probably, set the NVP behind a API gateway solution (IBM API Management?). It would balance the load and also help monetisation of invocations.